# What are best possible way to represent a tabular data in flatbuffer

Tags: flatbuffers

I have tabular data (header, data rows/columns). One can assume it to be in csv format for representation purpose.

- There is header row as column labels, may not be in same sequence always. But for each label name datatype is known upfront
- Number of columns are *fixed*, each column is *different* datatype
- Number of rows are *variable*

I am new to Flatbuffers so want to know best possible way to represent tabular data in Flatbuffers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
table Row {
  col1:int;  // These can each be their own data type.
  col2:string;
  ..
  // Fixed number of columns.
}

table Root {
  rows:[Row];  // vector of rows, variable length.
}

root_type Root;
```

Note that in this case FlatBuffers' use of `table` is very different from a database table.

Comment: Thanks @Aardappel. For `table` yes I understand so I use `tabular` to distinguish. Is a new schema possible where instead of `table Row {...}` I be able to use `table/struct Col {...}` because in that case all values be of same data type and will be simply scalar. Will this change give any possible buffer size advantage?

Comment: Yes, you could alternatively do: `table Root { col1:[int]; col2:[string]; }` The size advantages will typically be minimal though, so I'd choose which is easier to process or makes most sense.